# Task run by celery worker with supervisor getting incorrect value for datetime.date.today()

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, supervisord, celerybeat

I have a task which runs periodically using celery beat. Both celery beat and celery worker (in separate queue) are running using supervisor.

The task is storing the run date using python's `datetime.date.today()` function.
The issue is that `datetime.date.today()` returns proper date when the worker is restarted but the following days when the same task is invoked using celery beat, the `datetime.date.today()` function returns the same date when worker restarted instead of current date.

The task is running in utc timezone and i cross checked the date of execution. The same is happening when i tried passing run date as `args` using celery beat( In this case, it was returning celery beat's start/restart date instead of current date). 
I still cannot figure why this is happening. The server system date/ time seems to be working properly.

Here is the supervisor config for celery beat and celery worker queue (this is not entire config, just relevant blocks)

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/dir/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trac
pidfile=supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)


[program:celery_worker_custom_queue]
environment =
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8,
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8

command = /usr/local/bin/celery  --concurrency=5  -A config worker -l info -Q custom_queue -n workername@%%h
directory = /path/to/dir
priority = 2
user = user
numprocs = numprocs
stderr_logfile = log_file_path
stdout_logfile = log_file_path
autostart = true
autorestart = true


[program:celery_beat]
environment =
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8,
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8

command = /usr/local/bin/celery -A config beat -l info
directory = /path/to/dir
priority = 3
user = user
numprocs = numprocs
stderr_logfile = log_file_path
stdout_logfile = log_file_path
autostart = true
autorestart = true
```

I could not find any similar issue on web when i checked. Also, i cannot afford to remove supervisor.

Is there anything i can do in config? Also, i'm working with such setup for the first time, am i missing something conceptually? please help

**Edit:**
I have tested this on my local machine, it runs properly without supervisor. The task code is as follows (removed code where run date is not used)

```
 import datetime as dt

 run_date = (dt.date.today()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

 @celeryApp.task(bind=True, name="api_task",queue="custom_queue")
 def api_task(self, start_date=run_date):
   api_run_date = start_date
   #api calls and object calculations; api_run_date is not used anywhere..
   task_status(obj=status_obj, status=True, run_date=api_run_date)

 def task_status(obj, status=False, run_date=run_date):
    is_done = status
    # print(obj,' - ',run_date,' - ',is_done)
    done, created = ModelName.objects.update_or_create(date=run_date, defaults={'is_done': is_done}, obj_inst=obj)
    done.save()
```

Comment: Does it work correctly if run without supervisord? Also, could you post the code of the task?

Comment: @TomášLinhart updated details and added task code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the way you work with the date. You store the `datetime.date.today()` value in a `run_date` global variable and then use this as a default value for the `start_date` argument of your task. But default argument values are evaluated only once when the function is defined in Python. So unless you actually provide a value for `start_date` when calling the `api_task`, you work with the same value always. The value is the value of `run_date` global variable, which in turn gets evaluated only once when the module is first imported.

Correct way of handling this would be like this:

```
def api_task(self, start_date=None):
   # use `start_date` if given or current date
   api_run_date = start_date or dt.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   #api calls and object calculations; api_run_date is not used anywhere..
   task_status(obj=status_obj, status=True, run_date=api_run_date)
```

Comment: i finally got to test this. intially i was doing the same mistake of relying on global variables for else condition. It was fetching the same incorrect results. Then i re-read your solution. Now it works. I have tested this for 3 days now. everything is working fine. Thanks!